# React Hover to conditional render component

Tags: reactjs

this is my code so far

```
class PortfolioList extends Component{


render(){
    const {column , styevariation } = this.props;
    const list = PortfolioListContent.slice(0 , this.props.item);
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            {list.map((value , index) => (

                <div className={`${column}`} key={index}>
                    <div className={`portfolio ${styevariation}`}>
                        <div className="thumbnail-inner" >
                            <div className={`thumbnail ${value.image}`}></div>
                            <div className={`bg-blr-image ${value.image}`}></div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="content" >

                        <div className="inner">
                            <p>{value.category}</p>
                            <h4><a href="/portfolio-details">{value.title}</a></h4>
                            <div className="btn-container">
                            <div className="portfolio-button">
                                <a className="rn-btn" href="/portfolio-details"><FaGithub /> Git </a>
                            </div>
                            <div className="portfolio-button">
                                <a className="rn-btn" href="/portfolio-details"><FaExternalLinkAlt /> Live </a>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>



                    </div>
                </div>

            ))}

        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

}

I want to conditionally render the div "content" and the child elements of content div when mouse is hovering over "thumbnail-inner" div. But hide content when mouse is not hovering over thumbnail-inner div.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this, but the idea is to add a variable in the state of the component which holds the current hovered item.
When a mouseEnter event enters to your `thumbnail-inner`, you update that variable with the current component index. And you set it to `-1` when a `mouseLeave` events happens in your `thumbnail-inner`.

Then you simply render the `content` conditionally by checking if the `this.state.selectedIndex === index`.

```
class PortfolioList extends Component {

state = {
    selectedItem: -1,
}

render(){
    const {column , styevariation } = this.props;
    const list = PortfolioListContent.slice(0 , this.props.item);
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            {list.map((value , index) => (

                <div className={`${column}`} key={index}>
                    <div className={`portfolio ${styevariation}`}>

                        <div 
                            className="thumbnail-inner" 
                            onMouseEnter={ () => { this.setState({selectedItem: index}) } } 
                            onMouseLeave={ () => { this.setState({selectedItem: -1}) } }>

                            <div className={`thumbnail ${value.image}`}></div>
                            <div className={`bg-blr-image ${value.image}`}></div>
                        </div>

                        {
                            this.state.selectedItem === index &&
                            <div className="content" >

                                <div className="inner">
                                    <p>{value.category}</p>
                                    <h4><a href="/portfolio-details">{value.title}</a></h4>
                                    <div className="btn-container">
                                    <div className="portfolio-button">
                                        <a className="rn-btn" href="/portfolio-details"><FaGithub /> Git </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="portfolio-button">
                                        <a className="rn-btn" href="/portfolio-details"><FaExternalLinkAlt /> Live </a>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>                            
                        }

                    </div>
                </div>

            ))}

        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Comment: This kind of works but when i try to hover over the buttons, they disappear lol

Comment: Maybe do the onMouseLeave on the “content” rather than the in the thumbnail inner

Comment: Or don’t do the onMouseLeave, the problem is how you will close the latest hover area

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add state for condition of hover (ex: "onHover"), the state is for conditional rendering the `<div className="content">`.
Second you need create function for hover and leaveHover(onMouseEnter & onMouseLeave) we call it `handleMouseEnter` for `onMouseEnter`, and we call it `handleMouseLeave` for `onMouseLeave`.

```
class PortfolioList extends Component {

state = {
    onHover: false,
}

handleMouseEnter() {
this.setState({onHover: true})
}

handleMouseLeave() {
this.setState({onHover: false})
}

render(){
    const {column , styevariation } = this.props;
    const list = PortfolioListContent.slice(0 , this.props.item);


    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            {list.map((value , index) => (

                <div className={`${column}`} key={index}>
                    <div className={`portfolio ${styevariation}`}>

                        <div 
                            className="thumbnail-inner" 
                            onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter} 
                            onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}>

                            <div className={`thumbnail ${value.image}`}></div>
                            <div className={`bg-blr-image ${value.image}`}></div>
                        </div>

                        {
                            this.state.onHover &&
                            <div className="content" >

                                <div className="inner">
                                    <p>{value.category}</p>
                                    <h4><a href="/portfolio-details">{value.title}</a></h4>
                                    <div className="btn-container">
                                    <div className="portfolio-button">
                                        <a className="rn-btn" href="/portfolio-details"><FaGithub /> Git </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="portfolio-button">
                                        <a className="rn-btn" href="/portfolio-details"><FaExternalLinkAlt /> Live </a>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>                            
                        }

                    </div>
                </div>

            ))}

        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```